# Do the numbers in Google Webmaster Tools factor in impressions and clicks from Google Places listings?

Tags: google-search-console, ranking, impressions, google-places

Do the numbers (impressions, position, rank, CTR, etc)  in Google Webmaster Tools factor in impressions and clicks from the Google Places local listings?

Comment: That's a great question. You initially think it would, but then it would surely throw out the average position if it did.

Answer (score -1):

Those numbers are from Google searches.   It represents clicks from Google places or Google search.

This will not include Google AdWords clicks.

Comment: Do you have any references to back up this answer?   It sounds good, but it would be a better answer if you linked to a relevant Google help document, or another website that explains it.